# I am getting an error that says no database found to handle

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, gradle, flyway

I am trying to do a migration in a spring boot project using flywaydb, and I am getting an error that says no database found to handle my url. The database is running in a docker container on my local machine. The database is the latest version of Oracle Express. My build.gradle file looks like this.

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile


plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.9.21'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version '1.9.21'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa' version '1.9.21'
    id 'org.flywaydb.flyway' version '10.4.1'
}

flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:3000/XEPDB1'
    user = 'pdbadmin'
    password = 'my_password'`your text`
    driver = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
    cleanDisabled = false
}

group = 'com.pdrake'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-database-oracle'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'
    implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core'
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6'
    implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    runtimeOnly 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc11'
}
tasks.withType(KotlinCompile) {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += '-Xjsr305=strict'
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I tried using different url combinations and I was hoping to at least see that it was seeing the database.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the IP and port of the url are correct

Comment: this is just a comment....